# Registration form to be submitted via ajax

Tags: ajax

I want to submit drupal'S registration form to be submitted via ajax .How can I acomplish this???

Comment: I haven't tried anythng yet just used a module modal forms but it opens up in a popup . And I want it to open with some animation effects which I am not been able insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the *Ajax submit for any form* module, here:

https://www.drupal.org/project/asaf

Comment: Thank You For such a noce module it helped me alot.Thanks once again..